# how to cut and post with newline in tcl?

Tags: tcl, eggdrop

```
catch [list exec find /home/gusman/mp3 -name "*$title*" -type f -printf "%f,"] song
```

I cut and divide in this way:
`regsub -all "," $song "\n" song`

And post them this way
`putserv "notice $nick :$song"`

The result only posts one line
`<Botnick>: Title song.mp3`

Whereas in the search file there are several song titles

I want to post it like this:
`<Botnick>:1 Title song.mp3`
`<Botnick>:2 Title song.mp3`
`<Botnick>:3 Title song.mp3`
according to the number of search results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you print with the extra `,` characters and replace them afterwards with newlines, instead of using newlines directly?

I guess you're also missing a `split` and a `foreach` loop.

This works for me:

```
catch [list exec find /home/gusman/mp3 -name "*$title*" -type f] songs
foreach song [split $songs \n] {
    putserv "notice $nick :$song"
}
```

Comment: I like this, Thanks